# Theano With Python2.7: SGD with multiple losses

Tags: python, python-2.7, theano

After Theano being praised to me I thought I'd make my first steps with a specific form of SGD. I've got a parameter vector theta which I want to optimise My loss function return a vector containing the column sums of the squared loss between a matrix A and B. Each of the elements is an independent loss for a specific dimension using the broadcasted theta. Theta should be updated so that the next iteration the loss for each dimension is lower. I chose this because the data (X,Y) is given in this way.

Now the tutorial says T.grad() should be used to get the gradient for the updates. But T.grad doesn't allow me to calculate the gradient for non-scalars. The tutorial (http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/gradients.html) says 'Scalar costs only can be directly handled by grad. Arrays are handled through repeated applications.' So I tried (admitably an ugly attempt) to calculate the gradient for each of the losses. How do I calculate gradients for a multiple losses? And is there a clean, best-practice way? Is that even correct? Something else that I should consider?

Martin

```
import numpy
from theano import tensor as T
from theano import function
from theano import shared

alpha = 0.00001
theta = shared(numpy.random.rand(10), name='theta')
X = T.dmatrix(name='X')
Y = T.dmatrix(name='Y')
losses = T.sqr(theta * X - Y).sum(axis=0)
```

This is where it is getting weird:
Because T.grad(loss, theta) throws TypeError: cost must be a scalar. So I got this ugly attempt:

```
d_losses = [T.grad(losses[i], theta) for i in xrange(len(theta.get_value()))] 
updates = [(theta, theta - numpy.array(alpha) * d_losses)]
```

When I want to compile it I get this:

```
    >>> f = function(inputs=[A], outputs=loss, updates=updates)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/function.py", line 266, in function
    profile=profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 489, in pfunc
    no_default_updates=no_default_updates)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/pfunc.py", line 202, in rebuild_collect_shared
    update_val = store_into.type.filter_variable(update_val)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/type.py", line 206, in filter_variable
    other = self.Constant(type=self, data=other)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/var.py", line 732, in __init__
    Constant.__init__(self, type, data, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gof/graph.py", line 443, in __init__
    self.data = type.filter(data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/type.py", line 115, in filter
    up_dtype = scal.upcast(self.dtype, data.dtype)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/scalar/basic.py", line 67, in upcast
    rval = str(z.dtype)
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'dtype'
```

Comment: Why do you want several losses? You can have a scalar loss and derive w.r.t. to each component of theta.

Comment: so you mean d_loss = [T.grad(loss,theta[i]) for i in xrange(len(theta.get_value()))] ? Or how would I do that? The inital thought was that each feature has has it's own loss which I wanted to capture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mikael Rousson points out in a comment, for the purposes of the gradient you probably don't need to deal with separate losses; just sum up all the loss components into a scalar and then compute the partial derivatives with respect to the vector of parameters, yielding a vector of gradients.

So add

```
loss = losses.sum()
```

or directly define a scalar loss

```
loss = T.sqr(theta * X - Y).sum()
```

then use

```
d_losses = T.grad(loss, theta)
updates = [(theta, theta - alpha * d_losses)]
```

`d_losses[0]` equals the partial derivative of `loss` with respect to `theta[0]` but the only term in `loss` that involves `theta[0]` is the component of the sum over the first element of `losses` so it is also equal to the partial derivative of `losses[0]` with respect to `theta[0]` which is exactly what you want,  I think.

Comment: that makes sense. Thank you!